# How to pass parameters to function via variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am executing function in separate thread and want to pass arguments via queue. So function should be idealy able to accept all variables encapsulated in one variable

something like:

```
v = ('arg1', kwarg1='val1', kwarg2='val2')

def print_arg(*args, **kwargs):
    print('args:{}\nkwargs:{}'.format(args, kwargs))

print_arg(v)
```

Is there any simple way how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way for you to do this may be to build the queue in your main thread and pass it as an argument to the thread you create:

```
q = queue.Queue()   
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=main_function,args(q,other_args))
```

In either thread, use the put method to add information to the queue as strings:

```
q.put(str(important_variable))
```

Retrieve this information from the queue with the get method

```
important_variable = q.get()
```

If passing multiple variables or information, use multiple queues or structure what you put into the queue so that you know what it is you're pulling out of the queue.

Comment: i was not asking how to handle queues, i was asking i there is simple way to pass multiple args and kwargs via some variable. be aware that important_variable != str(important_variable), so by this step you are passing something different

Answer (score 0):

While yes, you *can* store all arguments in a single variable, you still need to store the positional arguments separately from the keyword arguments. There is no data structure that can function as a sequence and a mapping at the same time.

Here's one way to do it:

```
v = ['arg1'], {'kwarg1': 'val1', 'kwarg2': 'val2'}
print_arg(*v[0], **v[1])
```

This is a bit tedious and hard to read, so we can encapsulate the whole thing in a class:

```
class ArgumentBundle:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def call(self, function):
        return function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)

v = ArgumentBundle('arg1', kwarg1='val1', kwarg2='val2')
v.call(print_arg)
```